# Shell Script can be executed from terminal but not from the crontab

Tags: php, shell, cron

I have to export products in the .csv or .txt file automatically all the time for the price compare feeds. 
First, I was able to export products only via URL like this:
`https://site-name.com/Process/Cron.php?run=1&engine=ExportProducts&service=1&profile_id=90&export_file=testcron_export.csv`
But, I needed to export the products automatically on some time interval and for that I found a way to run the URL for exports of products in .csv or .txt file from terminal with the following command:

```
REQUEST_URI=‘Process/Cron.php’ SCRIPT_NAME=‘Process/Cron.php’ php-cgi -f Process/Cron.php run=1 engine=ExportProducts service=1 id=90 export_file=testcron_export.csv
```

And the products were exported successfully.

But, when I am setting up this command in the crontab, it’s not executed.

I tried using different ways, one of the ways is:
Copied the command (from above) in bash script and executed it successfully from terminal, but when I set-up the bash script in the crontab it's not executed.

These are all the combinations that I’ve tried in the crontab:

```
*/2 * * * * REQUEST_URI=‘Process/Cron.php’ SCRIPT_NAME=‘Process/Cron.php’ php-cgi -f Process/Cron.php run=1 engine=ExportProducts service=1 id=90 export_file=testcron_export.csv
*/2 * * * * ./testcron2.sh
*/2 * * * * ~/www.site_name.com/testcron2.sh
*/2 * * * * sh /home/site_name/SspStore/testcron2.sh
*/2 * * * * sh testcron2.sh
*/2 * * * * /bin/sh testcron2.sh
*/2 * * * * /bin/sh /home/site_name/SspStore/testcron2.sh
*/2 * * * * php-cgi -f REQUEST_URI=‘Process/CoreCron.php’ SCRIPT_NAME=‘Process/Cron.php’ Process/Cron.php run=1 engine=ExportProducts service=1 id=90 export_file=testcron_export.csv
*/2 * * * * usr/bin/sh testcron2.sh
*/2 * * * * usr/bin/sh /home/site_name/SspStore/testcron2.sh
```

PS. The shell script (testcron2.sh) is in the home directory of the shop.
Maybe the problem is with php-cgi that cannot be executed from terminal or I am missing something?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: maybe the path to the php script is wrong.
add in your .sh script "cd /home/site_name/SspStore" as a first line. Or the path where you can access the 'Process/CoreCron.php' script directly.
also the line 1 and 8 in cron will not run since the cron is being called from your user directory that might not correspond with your application path.

Comment: I'd look carefully into whether something in your shell session is different from the session being executed by cron. The quotes in your env exports seem a little scary, too, though I don't know if that's a browser issue or something... you should also try absolute paths, as cron [may or may not start its session in your home directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38956/175844). Finally, I'd think you could add output redirection to get the results of this command in a file somewhere, which might give you a hint.

Comment: @MicPic Thanks for your help.
I just added:
"cd /home/site_name/SspStore" as a first line in my .sh script and then the script was executed successfully.
Thanks again.